# GIF image not showing up on iphones

Tags: ios, iphone, gif

I have a gif image that ends in .gif  It shows up correctly on android phones and chrome.  Iphones are unable to show the gif.  An image of what it should look like, and what it shows on an Iphone are below.

The iphone im testing with is Iphone 6 ios 11.4

Image on iphones for the gif, as it is not showing up.

[image]

Blinking gif showing up on other browsers and phones.

[image: **enter image description here**]

Answer (score 0):

If you use the SDWebImage library for image loading and caching in your project, you will find a class named FLAnimatedImage. Using this you can easily integrate a GIF.

```
FLAnimatedImage *image = [[FLAnimatedImage alloc] initWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"<your_file_name>" ofType:@"gif"]]];

    [yourImageView setAnimatedImage:image];
    __weak typeof(self) weakself = self;
    yourImageView.loopCompletionBlock = ^(NSUInteger loopCountRemaining) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [weakself.yourImageView startAnimating];
        });
    };
```

Comment: I'll take a look at this.  Any idea why this occurs though?